Interpretation of “まとめてきている” and “〜てきている” with similar verbs in the same form
Can this only mean “is compiling”, ongoing action, or can it also mean “has compiled”, completed action with achieved purpose but implying a longer, more gradual process than “まとめている” typically would?

You've already asked this, so I assume you already understand that the likely interpretation depends on the verb's meaning. Let me focus on the case of まとめる.
When まとめる means "to summarize" or "to wrap up", this is an action that doesn't take a long time by definition, so まとめてきている is very unlikely to refer to a gradual process. The likely interpretation of まとめてきている is "I've summarized and come here", i.e., "I've brought the summary":

昨日の会議の議事録をまとめてきています。
I've brought the summary of the minutes from yesterday's meeting.

When まとめる means "to lead/manage/coordinate (an organization)", this is an action that takes time, so まとめてくる works exactly like 働いてきた/働いてきている in your previous question:

10年間この会社をまとめてきています。
I've been managing this company for 10 years.

The intransitive version of まとめる is まとまる, and this can be combined with (-て)くる with the meaning of "has started", just like 暗くなってきている/慣れてきている:

クラスはひとつにまとまってきています。
The class is becoming more united / started to be united.


Ahh, I see the reason I was confused about the context I encountered it in was because I interpreted “まとめる” as something that takes a long time, as in compiling results. So say with a more gradual verb such as “暗くなってきている” it would mean in-progress? I completely overlooked the “sumarized and brought it” interpretation of the context I encountered it in.

@Zorf I don't know why but the in-progress reading happens only with まとまる. You can say (議論/考え/論文が)まとまってきた ("it's starting to come together"), but not まとめてきた.
